# How to add values to Live Chart Pies?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts

```
private void MapPie()
{
    List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
    var NameLables = new List<string>();

    CON.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDB"].ConnectionString;
    CON.Open();
    CMD = new SqlCommand("select top (5) * from tblRecordDefects order by qty desc", CON);
    RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
    while (RDR.Read())
    {
        allValues.Add(Convert.ToString(RDR["qty"]));
        var day = RDR.GetString(RDR.GetOrdinal("dname"));
        NameLables.Add(day);
    }

    Func<ChartPoint, string> labelPoint = chartPoint =>
    string.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);

    DataContext = this;
}
```

How can I get `RDR["qty"]` and `RDR.GetString(RDR.GetOrdinal("dname"))` to here `string.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);`. I have tried different ways like `toArray()` and all, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Odd why you are keeping the data in two separate lists as opposed to a tuple of both but anyway here are two version of the code, one with keeping it in two lists like you do now and the other without.

```
private void MakeData()
    {
        List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
        var NameLables = new List<string>();

        //Simulate the SQL query by looping over X times
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            allValues.Add((i + 1).ToString());
            NameLables.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        }
        seriesCol = new SeriesCollection();

        seriesCol.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, allValues.Count).Select(x => new PieSeries { Title = NameLables[x], Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { new ObservableValue(double.Parse(allValues[x])) } }));
    }
```

And the second version

```
private void MakeData2()
    {
        var temp = new SeriesCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var dname = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            var qty = i;
            temp.Add(new PieSeries { Title = dname, Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { new ObservableValue(qty) } });
        }

        seriesCol = temp;

    }
```

In both of these examples the view model also has a property called seriesCol

```
private SeriesCollection _seriesCol;
    public virtual SeriesCollection seriesCol
    {
        get { return _seriesCol; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => seriesCol, ref _seriesCol, value);
        }
    }
```

You view then binds to that

```
<lvc:PieChart Grid.Row="1" Series="{Binding Path=seriesCol}"/>
```

Comment: Good explanation. You forgot to mention that you are using MVVMLight. That Set lambda was new to me.

Comment: Sorry force of habit using MVVMLight for everything, it is a good framework!

Comment: Thanks this helped! Can i know how to show lables like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q8-A8uJrqDPi00zJDATbs50YsBozzlnC)